# Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512CryptoServiceProvider' from assembly Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral

Tags: c#, .net, security

I load Cryptography Providers dynamically using this code

```
string hashAlgoTypeString =
         ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[HashAlgorithmProviderConfiguration];
if (hashAlgoTypeString != null)
{
    Type hashAlgoType = Type.GetType(hashAlgoTypeString, true);
    return (HashAlgorithm) Activator.CreateInstance(hashAlgoType);
}
```

The hashAlgoTypeString is a full qualified name to one of *CryptoServiceProviders* set in my *Web.config*

I don't have any problems loading these

```
System.Security.Cryptography.DESCryptoServiceProvider
System.Security.Cryptography.DSACryptoServiceProvider
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
System.Security.Cryptography.RC2CryptoServiceProvider
System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider
System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
```

However, the following CryptoServiceProviders all throw the "*Could not load type*" exception.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA384CryptoServiceProvider
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512CryptoServiceProvider
```

What could be the issue with these four providers?

I'm running Windows 7 x64 with .NET 4.5.2

In GAC

```
System.Security v2.0.0.0
mscorlib v2.0.0.0 for x86 and AMD64
```

**Edit**

I am able to instantiate all four

```
        var Aes = new System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        var sha256 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
        var sha384 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA384CryptoServiceProvider();
        var sha512 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512CryptoServiceProvider();
```

and use them from my code without issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the value returned from Web.config

```
string hashAlgoTypeString =
     ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[HashAlgorithmProviderConfiguration];
```

Instead of

```
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider
```

it should be fully qualified name

```
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512CryptoServiceProvider, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not defined in the same dll!

The ones that work are in mscorlib.dll, whereas the ones that don't work are in System.Core.dll

Probably if you add a reference to System.Core.dll it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but system.core is included by default. In Visual Studio 2013+ you can't add it as a reference, you will get an error "A reference to 'System.Core' could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system"

Comment: However, your answer pointed us to a correct solution. In the Web.config we specified only the Provider Name (as System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider) Instead we should specify the full name ""System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512CryptoServiceProvider, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"